# any ruby library that produces a nice "gauge" graph image that doesn't require javascript?

Tags: ruby, charts, rubygems, gauge

I really like the Google Charts "gauge" graph.  I would like to use it in a formatted HTML email however as email doesn't allow javascript I can't do this.

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge.html

Any ruby library or alternative approach available that would allow a "gauge" graph of similar high quality as the above-mentioned google one to be produced and used in a formatted html email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Image Charts has a "gauge" graph.

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/chart_wizard.html

It's not quite as slick as the javascript version, but it might do.

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxl=0:|slow|faster|crazy&chxt=y&chs=300x150&cht=gm&chd=t:70&chl=Groovy

Comment: yeah I saw this Chris - I just didn't like it's look/quality compared to the one I mentioned - it's a fallback through

Answer (score 0):

There's [rchart](http://amardaxini.github.com/).

There's [gerbilcharts](http://gerbilcharts.rubyforge.org/), but you might need to convert from SVG to an image depending on your needs.

There's [gruff](http://nubyonrails.com/pages/gruff).

Comment: unfortunately they don't seem to (at this point in time) have a "gauge" graph currently...